# Change password rerset link

Tags: laravel-5, passwords

I use a standard authorization system in larawe. When sending a message to reset the password, the link has the form http: // localhost / password / reset / {token}

In the application files, I did not find a representation for this letter. How can I change the link to a normal address, not a localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is generated from your .env file. So look at the value for APP_URL in .env and change it to whatever you need.